# How to catch runtime errors from native code in python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have the following problem, Lets have this python function

```
def func():
   run some code here which calls some native code
```

Inside func() I am calling some functions which in turn calls some native C code.
If any crash happens the whole python process crashes alltoghether.

How is possible to catch and recover from such errors?
One way that came to my mind is run this function in a separate process, but not just starting another process because there is a lot of memory and objects used by the function, will be very hard to split that. Is there something like fork() in C available in python, to create a copy of the same exact process with same memory structures and etc?

Or maybe other ideas?

Update:
It seems that there is no real way of catching the C runtime errors in python, those are at a lower level and crashes the whole Python virtual machine.

As solutions you currently have two options:

1. Use os.fork() but work only in unix like OS env.
2. Use multiprocessing and a shared memory model to share big objects between processes. Usual serialization will just not work with objects that have multi-gigabytes in memory (you will just run out of memory). However there is a very good python library called Ray (https://docs.ray.io/en/master/) that performs in-memory big objects serialization using shared memory model and it's ideal for BigData/ML workloads - highly recommended.

Comment: why dont you use `try` and `except`?

Comment: If it is raising an exception, you should catch the exception. If it is really "crashing" without an exception, then it has a severe bug and you cannot do anything about that.

Comment: `fork` exists in python as long as you are on a platoform that supports it. Linux/Mac: Yes, Windows: No. In fact, `multiprocessing.Process` forks when it can.

Comment: If the C code is interacting with a bunch of python objects, it may be easier to have a common serialization format (json, msgpack, etc...) so that the C code unpacks that data into C structures and gets rid of the python object complication. Then it would be relatively easy to create a C only process and send the data.

Comment: try/except does not handle underlying C runtime errors.

Comment: As Corneliu said try/except not much help for segfaults.

Comment: Is the native code third party? If so can you control what you pass to it to catch errors before a hard crash? If you maintain the native code then you can probably improve the error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are running on an operating system that supports `fork` that's already how the `multiprocessing` module creates subprocesses. You could `os.fork`, `multiprocessing.Process` or `multiprocessing.Pool` to get what you want. You can also use the `os.fork()` call on these systems.

Comment: Thank you, I already found out that os.fork provides this functionality.